# Extjs 4 :Disable all the input elemets in an Extjs form at once

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4, element

I have created a extjs form which is divided into 2 parts using column layout and have almost 10-15 input elements in it. How can i disable all these input elements at a time depending on a condition. Currently i have created a function which fetchs all the components in a form and using ext.each loop through each element to disable them

Here is the function that i use

```
function prepare_form_view(form){
    var f=Ext.getCmp(form);
    var els=f.query('component');
    Ext.each(els,function(o){
        var xtype=o.getXType();
        if(xtype=='textfield'||xtype=='combobox'||xtype=='datefield'||xtype=='textareafield'||xtype=='button'){
            o.disabledCls='myDisabledClass';
            o.disable();
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any alternative way so that I can disable all elements without looping through each and every elements. ***I want to use this function with other forms too***. I looking for something like 'setFieldDefult' function.

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368466/extjs4-how-to-disable-all-fields-and-all-buttons-on-a-panel-recursively)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using FormPanel in ExtJs 4.x this is what you are looking for -

```
yourFormPanel.getForm().applyToFields({disabled:true});
```

The `getForm()` method returns the Ext.form.Basic object, with this class, you also could access to all the fields on this form with `getFields()`, then you could iterator all the fields to do anything.

Hope this helps and good luck:-)

Answer (score 4):

What about panel's disable/enable method? This seems much easier.

```
panel.disable();

panel.enable();
```

Comment: It also disables the panel's toolbar, otherwise this works well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion.. Since, you say your form is divided into two parts why don't you put them in a [FieldSet](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldSet) ? You can disable the fieldset as a whole with one method ie, [setDisabled](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldSet-method-setDisabled).

This will avoid the looping of components and disabling / enabling them one after the another.

Comment: Thank you for reply Abdel. but as i said i want to use this function with other forms too.And different forms have different layout...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [cascade](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-cascade) function of the form panel which is the ExtJs way to to do it but if  you check the source code of the cascade function you will see that it uses a for loop also. The only benifit of using the cascade function is that it will work also for forms with nested panels. I think that your implementation will not work properly a case like that.