# ExtJs4 how to disable all fields and all buttons on a panel recursively

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to disable all clickable, editable components on my panel.

Calling `panel.disable()` grays it out, but buttons are still clickable.
The same result gives `panel.cascade` with a function that disables each component.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using ExtJs **4.x**, this is what you are looking for -

```
myFormPanel.query('.field, .button').forEach(function(c){c.setDisabled(false);});
```

(Modify your selector based on the complexity of your form. You can just use .component and it will disable all component in your form)

See also - [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)

If you are using **3.x**, you can achieve the same effect in two steps like this -

```
myFormPanel.buttons.forEach(function(btn){btn.setDisabled(true);}); //disable all buttons
myFormPanel.getForm().items.each(function(itm){itm.setDisabled(true)}); //disable all fields
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `c.setDisabled(true)` based on the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-setDisabled). I am refering to Extjs 4.2.1 of course.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you used a `FormPanel` you can use this method to get form:

```
getForm() // see http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getForm
```

This will return the `Ext.form.Basic` object. From here you have access to all the fields on this form with method:

```
getFields() // see http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getFields
```

Now cou can iterate through the field and disable them. Notice also the method `applyToFields()`  where you can pass your object. See API information: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-applyToFields

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is a better solution to disabling all form fields inside a form panel.

```
var formPanelName = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#formPanelId field');
for(var i= 0; i < formPanelName.length; i++) {
   formPanelName[i].setDisabled(true);
}
```

Just get a reference to the form panel fields. Iterate over each field and use the setDisabled function to set its readOnly attribute to true.

You can also take it a set further and grab the entire form Panel. This solution above only grabs individual sections of the form panel by its ID. extjs 4

Answer (score 0):

For those manually adding fieldsets and fields to a form panel, ExtJS doesn't require you to add components directly to the form, by doing a getForm() first.  It's mainly for convenience, and allows standard functionality to work properly.  So whatever component you did the 'add' from, iterate from that component.

**Example 1:**

Normally you should not use the 'id' to get a component since it's set dynamically.  But this shows how you could get the form panel itself using the getCmp.

```
            var formPanel = Ext.getCmp('id-of-component');
            var fieldSet = Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldSet', {
                title: 'field set'                    
            });
            formPanel.add(fieldSet);
```

*When iterating, you would do this:*

```
formPanel.each(function(item) {
  alert(item.title);
});
```

**Example 2:**

In this example, we add to the actual form itself, so the iteration looks slightly different.

```
            var formPanel = Ext.getCmp('id-of-component');
            var fieldSet = Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldSet', {
                title: 'field set'                    
            });
            formPanel.getForm().add(fieldSet);
```

*When iterating, you would do this:*

```
formPanel.getForm().each(function(item) {
  alert(item.title);
});
```